# Linux server doesn't accept TCP connections

Tags: linux, tcp

For two different projects I run Linux servers and experience a similar problem. After a few weeks, the systems don't accept any TCP connections from the outside. It's not possible to SSH to the system anymore and all other TCP connections are also denied. The system still responds to a ping.

One system runs Docker and three MongoDB containers. The other system runs Docker and five Minio containers. No other software is installed on these systems. Both systems run with an ISP, so without SSH I cannot investigate much.

Does anyone know where I should start to look?

Comment: Use a console-like connection to log directly, linux will deny TCP connection if a) too many process b) disk full c) VM froze due to I/O d)) other reasons. You have to connect to investigate.

Comment: As @Archemar suggests, your hoster should provide an alternative way to login used for the case SSH is not working. Try to use it to investigate. If there is no such way, contact you hoster.